# Keyboard shortcuts in comments

Tags: feature-request, comment, keyboard-shortcuts

I personally like to use shortcuts such as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to toggle italics or bold when writing answers. It turns out that when writing down a comment, they don't work and bring out something else instead, depending on the settings of the browser. It is a little bit annoying to have to come back from there and then add <kbd>*</kbd>s manually.

Just a tiny little thing, but if I'm not alone out there thinking that would be a useful feature, maybe worth looking at.

Comment: This feature request seems quite similar: [Formatting Keyboard Shortcuts for Comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14756). And one of the answers mentions Greasemonkey script as a possible workaround. (As I do not use Greasemonkey, I did not test it so I cannot confirm whether it actually works.)

Comment: Since [the last time](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27941/displaying-reasons-for-reopening) almost immediately after I posted a similar comment you have deleted the question, I will point out explicitly that the above link goes to Meta Stack Exchange not this this local meta (Mathematics Meta). And even if it were on the same meta, sometimes [duplicates can be useful](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9586/avoiding-duplicates/9588#9588).

Comment: @MartinSleziak sorry I didn't mean to be rude by deleting the question, just thought it would save some time for everyone. Thanks for your useful comments!

Comment: I did not intend to imply that the deletion was in some way impolite. I just wasn't sure whether you noticed that the link was to a different meta, so this time I specifically pointed this out. It is always a judgement call whether to keep the question if the issue has been discussed before or elsewhere. But for example in this specific case even if the question about keyboard shortcuts does not generate much discussion, at least the user who think that it is a good idea might notice the link given in the first comment and upvote the feature request on the main meta.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I had not noticed the first time, thanks. So I guess this implies that such questions would be more appropriate on the "main" meta in any case.

Comment: Since the last few comments are not really related to your question and are more about "Where to ask questions like this?" I would suggest to continue it elsewhere. I am not sure whether this issue is important enough to create a new question on meta (and I did not search whether there already is one) - I will leave a few comments [here in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/64952/2018/3/4).