# Why can't I edit a new question in place of a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, editing, asking-questions, exact-duplicates, closed-questions

I have $5$ or so duplicate/closed questions, which is hurting my "positive question record" statistic. So, I edited a useless duplicate question and asked a new question, which I was told "if you want to ask a different question, don't edit a duplicate."

I am wondering why this is the case, as editing a new question in place of an old dup would be beneficial to the cite. It would remove a useless duplicate and add a new useful question. Why isn't this allowed?

Comment: Duplicates iirc do not count against you. If you think it is useless then in some circumstances you can delete the question. People have generally already voted and commented on a question so you shouldn’t repurpose it into a new unrelated question. Even if not, it takes some effort from other people to undo linking them as a duplicate. Better to start fresh

Comment: The duplicates get closed, which does affect my question record.

Comment: Well, I am wrong (sorry), but making the question good matters much more, see [Does marking an earlier question as a duplicate of a newer one harm the asker?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259868/does-marking-an-earlier-question-as-a-duplicate-of-a-newer-one-harm-the-asker), and also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292248/ and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251825/

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "positive question record"? Are you asking in connection with possibility [of a question ban](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/post-ban/info)? Or do you mean the question record used in the calculation of the [Curious, Inquisitive and Socratic badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges)?

Comment: For the badges.

Comment: ah. In which case, I completely misunderstood, sorry.

Comment: Because it's weird. New questions are for new posts. Chill out and you'll have a better time and fewer things to complain about on meta.

Comment: You don't need no stinkin' badges.

Comment: Note that this question was answered in the comments in your [other question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34747/duplicates-allowed-from-years-ago-but-mine-are-not).

Comment: In case [Gerry Myerson's reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/162243) is lost on someone (unlikely, but still): [Stinking badges - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stinking_badges).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a new question, ask it in a new post.  It is inappropriate to replace a closed post with a different question, particularly when others have taken time to comment and/or answer the initial question.

The same goes for any post badly received, whether or not closed.  Do not subject helpful users to a moving target, no longer relevant to input others took the time to give you.

I add this only because the substance of your question has not been answered directly; but all the input above, is invaluable, as well.